# World doesn't load properly in launch file

Tags: gazebo, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm using Gazebo 9.6.0 and ROS Melodic in Ubuntu 18.04.

I have this launch file:

```
<launch>
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
        <arg name="world_name" value="$(find mybot_gazebo)/worlds/odom_bot.world"/>
        <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    </include>
</launch>
```

And this world file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.6">
  <world name="odom_world">
        <include>
            <uri>model://sun</uri>
        </include>

        <include>
            <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
        </include>


    <model name='Closed-room'>
      <pose frame=''>0.776409 -1.81109 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <link name='Wall_10'>
        <collision name='Wall_10_Collision'>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.75 0.15 2.5</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <pose frame=''>0 0 1.25 0 -0 0</pose>
          <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <bounce/>
            <friction>
              <torsional>
                <ode/>
              </torsional>
              <ode/>
            </friction>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name='Wall_10_Visual'>
          <pose frame=''>0 0 1.25 0 -0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.75 0.15 2.5</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
              <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
            </script>
            <ambient>1 1 1 1</ambient>
          </material>
          <meta>
            <layer>0</layer>
          </meta>
        </visual>
        <pose frame=''>7 5.3 0 0 -0 3.14159</pose>
        <self_collide>0</self_collide>
        <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
        <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      </link>
      <link name='Wall_5'>
        <collision name='Wall_5_Collision'>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>14.5 0.15 2.5</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <pose frame=''>0 0 1.25 0 -0 0</pose>
          <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <bounce/>
            <friction>
              <torsional>
                <ode/>
              </torsional>
              <ode/>
            </friction>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name='Wall_5_Visual'>
          <pose frame=''>0 0 1.25 0 -0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>14.5 0.15 2.5</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
              <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
            </script>
            <ambient>1 1 1 1</ambient>
          </material>
          <meta>
            <layer>0</layer>
          </meta>
        </visual>
        <pose frame=''>-0.125 5.3 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <self_collide>0</self_collide>
        <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
        <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      </link>
      <link name='Wall_7'>
        <collision name='Wall_7_Collision'>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>10.75 0.15 2.5</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <pose frame=''>0 0 1.25 0 -0 0</pose>
          <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <bounce/>
            <friction>
              <torsional>
                <ode/>
              </torsional>
              <ode/>
            </friction>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name='Wall_7_Visual'>
          <pose frame=''>0 0 1.25 0 -0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>10.75 0.15 2.5</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
              <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
            </script>
            <ambient>1 1 1 1</ambient>
          </material>
          <meta>
            <layer>0</layer>
          </meta>
        </visual>
        <pose frame=''>-7.3 -0 0 0 -0 -1.5708</pose>
        <self_collide>0</self_collide>
        <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
        <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      </link>
      <link name='Wall_8'>
        <collision name='Wall_8_Collision'>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>14.75 0.15 2.5</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <pose frame=''>0 0 1.25 0 -0 0</pose>
          <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <bounce/>
            <friction>
              <torsional>
                <ode/>
              </torsional>
              <ode/>
            </friction>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name='Wall_8_Visual'>
          <pose frame=''>0 0 1.25 0 -0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>14.75 0.15 2.5</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
              <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
            </script>
            <ambient>1 1 1 1</ambient>
          </material>
          <meta>
            <layer>0</layer>
          </meta>
        </visual>
        <pose frame=''>-0 -5.3 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <self_collide>0</self_collide>
        <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
        <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      </link>
      <link name='Wall_9'>
        <collision name='Wall_9_Collision'>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>10.75 0.15 2.5</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <pose frame=''>0 0 1.25 0 -0 0</pose>
          <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <bounce/>
            <friction>
              <torsional>
                <ode/>
              </torsional>
              <ode/>
            </friction>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name='Wall_9_Visual'>
          <pose frame=''>0 0 1.25 0 -0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>10.75 0.15 2.5</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
              <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
            </script>
            <ambient>1 1 1 1</ambient>
          </material>
          <meta>
            <layer>0</layer>
          </meta>
        </visual>
        <pose frame=''>7.3 -0 0 0 -0 1.5708</pose>
        <self_collide>0</self_collide>
        <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
        <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      </link>
      <static>1</static>
    </model>

  </world>
</sdf>
```

I have added a model (named Closed_room) did with Building Editor, but when I launch it, it doesn't show the model.

If I open the world with Gazebo, without using the launch file, it shows the building.

Do you know why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21923/world-doesn%27t-load-properly-in-launch-file/) by [VansFannel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4697/vansfannel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My guess is that roslaunch is not finding your world. You can try running Gazebo in verbose mode by adding this line:

`<arg name="verbose" value="true" />`

And if that's the problem, you should see an error message.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VansFannel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4697/vansfannel/) on 2019-02-10**:
Yes, you are right. Thanks!